# What factors determine the distribution of chemical energy between work and heat in a chemical reaction?

Tags: energy, heat

In the context of a chemical reaction, what factors determine the allocation of chemical energy between performing pressure–volume work and generating heat? Are there any key parameters or variables that dictate the proportion of energy converted into useful work versus dissipated as heat?

Comment: How long have you been thinking about this question before posting it? What are results of your thinking? What is your idea how it could be? Posts consisting just of questions are not received well on Chemistry SE site.

Comment: I have been thinking about this question for a while but need some direction. I am a high school student and my chemistry book says that energy is converted into either pressure-volume work or heat. I am really curious as to what determines the proportions

Comment: It is a question of experimental situation. If the experiment is done at constant volume, no work is produced, so that the heat produced is equal to the change of internal energy of the substances in reaction. If the experiment is done in contact with the atmospheric pressure, the volume may change a bit. But the heat produced is equal to the change of enthalpy of the substances in reaction.

Answer (score 1):

#### First Law of Thermodynamics

$$
\Delta U = q + W
$$

#### Work and Heat Depend on Process

Suppose we fix the initial and final states, then $\Delta U$ is fixed and constant, or:

$\Delta U = q + W = c \tag{1}$

Let's carry out severable *reversible* processes for a $PVT$ system, which means there is no nonmechanical work. For such processes the work is given by $W = -\int_{V_1}^{V_2}P\mathrm{d}V$, which is the area under the $P$-$V$ graph.

[image: visual representation of relation between work and heat]

Since area under process 3 is the highest, and process 1 is the lowest:

$$
W_3>W_2>W_1
$$

Sum of $W$ and $q$ is fixed, $\Delta U = c$, so,

$$
q_3<q_2<q_1
$$

#### Work and Heat Depend on Reversibility

It is known as the maximum work theorem:$^\text{1}$

> ...for all processes leading from the (a) specified initial state to the (a) specified final state of the primary system, the delivery of work is maximum (and the delivery of heat minimum) for a reversible process.

#### Reference

1. Called H. B. (2005). *Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatics*. 2$^\text{nd}$ ed. John Wiley & Sons Inc.